How to activate the OSGi console in web.xml
I am deploying my RAP application (i.e. .war file) into JBOSS server/Tomcat and after successful deployment, when i am trying to access the application but i am getting error as "Message BridgeServlet: /raptest_osgi" here raptest_osgi is war file name/context-root.
Please help me if anyone has some idea about this error.
Also I want to check OSGi console and i did telnet localhost 2020 but not able to open console can you please tell me how to open/access osgi console here??
I uncommented following lines in web.xml  commandline -console 2020 .
